# Button pressed automatically by default angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a menu of buttons, created dynamically in angular. If I pressed a button it shows me a table with some data. How to do when I open the application, the data for pressing the first button to be displayed by default? I mean, to not pressing the button? And then the value to be changed when I press another button. Is this possible? My code:

```
<div ng-repeat="group in groups" class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="switchGroup(group.id)">{{ '{{ group.code}}' }}</button>
</div>

<div ng-show="repartizations.length == 0"><h2> There is no schedule for this group.</h2></div>

<table class="table table-responsive" ng-show="repartizations.length > 0">
    ...
</table>
```

angular:

```
 $http.get('/api/group/specialization/' + $state.params.valueSpecialization).then(function (success) {
        $scope.groups = success.data;
    }
);

 $scope.switchGroup = function (groupId) {
    $http.get(
        '/api/repartition/group/' + groupId
    ).then(function (success) {
        $scope.repartizations = success.data;
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Invoke the method `$scope.switchGroup()` in the `success` callback method of *get specialization API*

```
$http.get('/api/group/specialization/' + $state.params.valueSpecialization).then(function (success) {
    $scope.groups = success.data;
    $scope.switchGroup($scope.groups[0].id) //Invoke the method
});
```

Comment: It's working, thank you :) I will accept your answer as long as I can.

Answer (score 0):

Write your button click code inside `ng-init()` function.
For Example:

```
<div ng-init="myInitFunction()">
    // your code
</div>
```

Now, in JS file

```
$scope.myInitFunction = function(){
   $http.get(
       '/api/repartition/group/' + groupId
   ).then(function (success) {
      $scope.repartizations = success.data;
   });
}
```

So whenever page is refreshed or reloaded you can see the data in table.